# marks I have set are deleted periodically

Tags: vim

My marks are randomly deleted while using gvim on my ubuntu machine.

For example, if I make some marks with `ma` and `mb`, tab away to firefox on another desktop, come back to gvim later and try to navigate to the marks `'a` and `'b` I get the error:

`E20: Mark not set`

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: Create some marks, tab away, come back, and show us the output of `:marks`.

Comment: oh, if it could be reproduced,  it should be a bug of firefox. :D , yes I am joking.

Comment: I will try to reproduce the error. Is there any way that I could have possibly unset marks by accident? Without typing `:delmark` which certainly I have not done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to be sure given the lack of details, but the most common reason for this is that the line was deleted.

For example with a buffer:

```
hello
world
test
```

And we add a mark on the third line (`test`).

If we now do `ddoHello<Esc>` this mark is removed, because the line was removed with `dd`. The mark is *not* restored if we add a new line 3.

There are some other scenarios where marks can get clobbered. e.g. when using `Vp` to replace the current line.

I suppose this could be considered both a feature and bug.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize marks were deleted when the line gets deleted. I also use `Vp` a lot. This is definitely the issue - any suggestions as far as work-arounds go?

Comment: @bvpx I'm not aware of any solutions, other than not using those commands ;-) But I didn't look very deeply into this.